# How to Enable TLS on SMTP server on windows 2012 R2?

Tags: ssl, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to enable TLS on SMTP server which installed on windows 2012 R2, however the option is grayed out.
PFA
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ2nl.png)

I have added certificated in regedit for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, however it didn't work.

Tried following steps provided here https://support.faxmaker.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4717769935506-Enabling-TLS-Configuration-on-IIS-SMTP-Server

Answer (score 0):

You need an SSL/TLS certificate to secure the SMTP communication. You can either obtain a certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority (CA) or generate a self-signed certificate. Then you'll have to install it on your server. Check [this question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/816572/how-to-enable-tls-for-smtp-in-ii6-on-windows-server-2012-r2), it's almost identical to yours and has several solutions.

Basically, here's what you have to do:

You should configure the TLS settings to enable secure communication. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Navigate to your SMTP server instance, right-click "**Default SMTP Virtual Server**," and choose "**Properties**." In the properties window, go to the "**Access**" tab, click the "**Certificate...**" button, and select a valid SSL/TLS certificate for your server. Next, go to the "**Delivery**" tab, click "**Outbound Security**," and select "**TLS Encryption**" as the authentication method. Finally, restart the SMTP service to apply the changes.

Comment: I can not see Certificate option in access tab, please check attached screenshot in question